# Parent exception types aren't caught when raising child exception types

Tags: python, exception

If I define my own exceptions

```
class AuthTokenExpired(Exception):
    pass
    
class TokenNotInDatabase(Exception):
    pass
    
class NoTokenInRequest(Exception):
    pass
```

Then I can catch any of them by saying

```
try:
    proc_that_raises()
except (AuthTokenExpired, TokenNotInDatabase, NoTokenInRequest):
    handle_exception()
```

So trying to be clever, I made a parent exception class and derived all these from it

```
class TokenProblem(Exception):
    pass

class AuthTokenExpired(TokenProblem):
    pass
        
class TokenNotInDatabase(TokenProblem):
    pass
        
class NoTokenInRequest(TokenProblem):
    pass
```

If I do that, then `except TokenProblem` doesn't fire on a TokenNotInDatabase. Why does this not work? TokenNotInDatabase is a TokenProblem, but the exception handling doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: The problem is with what you raise, not what you `except`. Show a [mcve] for a better answer. Also, keep in mind that if `B` subclasses `A`, then `B` is `A`, but `A` is not `B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple demo of how exception inheritance works:

```
>>> class TokenProblem(Exception):
...     pass
...
>>> class AuthTokenExpired(TokenProblem):
...     pass
...
>>> try:
...     raise AuthTokenExpired()
... except TokenProblem:
...     print("looks like I caught it")
...
looks like I caught it
```

Maybe in your `proc_that_raises` you're trying to raise `AuthTokenExpired` (the class) rather than an actual instance of it?

Comment: `raise AuthTokenExpired()` and  `raise AuthTokenExpired` are completely equivalent

Comment: Hm, so it is.  Must be some other kind of typo then?

Comment: Like I alluded to in my comment, OP is probably raising `TokenProblem` but `except`ing one of the subclasses. This will not work

Comment: This was more or less correct. I had a typo. One of my types was not inheriting.